# Simulate click with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, click, delay

i need to delay trigger click event i tried these i can see console logs in the time but trigger is not working.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("input[id='ceo-new-image']").trigger('click');
    console.log("Test");
}, 1000);
```

And i also tried this

```
$("#ceo-new-image").delay(3000).queue(function() {
    console.log("try");
    $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

I tried changing selectors and i'm sure they both works.
And also tried using .trigger('click') and .click() 
Do you have any ideas how can i make this work? or even how can i debug?

Comment: Does the element get added to the page during the delay?

Comment: Seems to work here: https://jsfiddle.net/fsqxhe1p/  Could you put together a basic piece of code that doesn't work as you expect in your question or jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes actually. I'm adding element first and then i need to delay it and trigger click.

Comment: @Chris yes the elements loaded by jquery i think thats the problem.

Comment: You are going to need to preventDefault on those handlers if they are bound to a button click event. Otherwise it wont delay, it will just try to submit.